# andengine - how can i get scene's children?

Tags: android, andengine

I need to get my scene's children. I'm using andengine and I'm trying to save game state somehow, but I don't really want to put my objects to an array, while creating level, I'd like to get those items just when I need to. So - the question Is - Is there any way, I can get scene's children? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `yourScene.getChildCount()` and `yourScene.getChildByIndex()` to iterate through things

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the method seems to be getChild() in AndEngine GLES1.

Comment: thanks - I never think of GLES1. Also, people should post what version of AndEngine they are using along with their questions.

Comment: right, i didn't point my version. i use of course gles2. thanks, i'll check it later and mark your answer or ask for more if i didn't manage ;)